# Detect URL change in SFSafariViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, sfsafariviewcontroller

I have a SFSafariViewController which opens when a user taps on a link in my app. I need to detect when the URL is changed, such that when it changes, the app displays an alert. How do we detect URL changes in SFSafariViewController?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You cannot do this.

`SFSafariViewController` is meant to send users off to a browser without caring too much where she goes to, but when she's done, she'll be right back in your app without any loss of context. There's only very few things you can customize.

The [official docs](https://developer.apple.com/reference/safariservices/sfsafariviewcontroller) mention (emphasis mine):

> If your app lets users view websites from anywhere on the Internet, use the SFSafariViewController class. If your app customizes, **interacts with**, or controls the display of web content, use the [WKWebView](https://developer.apple.com/reference/webkit/wkwebview) class.

It will require more work (especially some UI) to provide a nice browsing experience using `WKWebView`, but you're in control. The same goes for the older sibling, [`UIWebView`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiwebview). If you don't know which to use, [this comparison](http://nshipster.com/wkwebkit/) might help, although some things may have improved on the side of `WKWebView` since the article was written.

Comment: Note a big difference between `SFSafariViewController` and the others: `SFSafariViewController` shares data with the regular web browser on the device (and other `SFSafariViewController`s, including cookies and passwords. The only reason to use it (and the reason it was created in the first place) is for login / SSO and the like. If you don't need that, use an `UIWebView` or `WKWebView`. If you need those, the standard way of getting out of the `SFSafariViewController` automatically (after a successful login for instance), is to use a custom URL scheme.