# How to get URL in SFSafariViewWrapper if change

Tags: swift, swiftui, sfsafariviewcontroller

I have following code, that display SafariView in sheet.

```
Button(action: {self.showLogin = true}) {
    Text("OpenURL")
}
.sheet(isPresented: self.$showLogin) {
    SFSafariViewWrapper(url: URL(string: "https://google.com")!)
}
```

How can i get URL, when it changes in SafariView (by user)?

Comment: Similar question ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42192701/detect-url-change-in-sfsafariviewcontroller

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Detect URL change in SFSafariViewController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42192701/detect-url-change-in-sfsafariviewcontroller)